# Как получить интервал на основе created_at и нескольких записей?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-record

Есть поле `created_at`. Его содержимое выглядит следующим образом: `2017-08-27T19:20:43.737+03:00`.

Есть таблица, в которую периодически помещаются некоторые данные. Например, есть N записей. На основе этих записей я хочу получить следующую текстовую информацию:

> Записи создавались с примерным интервалом в **6** дней и около **23:57** часов.

Вот я хочу получить день и время. Время по сути похоже на среднее арифметическое, но метод `average` не работает:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function avg(timestamp without time zone) does not exist

А как получить день — я честно даже не знаю в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 3):

Проще всего вычислить количество дней, в течение которых создавались записи. Для этого можно воспользоваться либо чистым SQL-запросом (не очень хорошо с точки зрения RoR)

```
SELECT MAX(created_at) - MIN(created_at) AS days FROM pages
```

результат выполнения которого можно получить при помощи метода модели `count_by_sql`

```
Page.count_by_sql('SELECT MAX(created_at) - MIN(created_at) AS days FROM Pages')
```

Либо извлечь максимальное и минимальное значение `created_at` отдельными запросами, которые в RoR будут иметь класс `Time`. Можно вычесть полученные даты друг из друга и поделить на количество секунд в сутках. Так мы тоже получим количество дней, в течение которых размещались записи

```
(Page.maximum(:created_at) - Page.minimum(:created_at)) / 3600 / 24
```

Для получения среднего времени в течении суток, придется от каждого datetime-значения "отрезать" дату и вычислить среднее по времени. Так как мы работаем в RoR и решение задачи средствами СУБД не поощряется (и не так тривиально, как первая задача), можно извлечь все значения `created_at` в память ruby-программы (при условии, что записей не много) и вычислить среднее время, средствами Ruby/RoR

```
arr = Page.pluck(:created_at)
avg = arr.map do |t|
  h, m, s = t.strftime('%H:%M:%S').split(':').map(&:to_i)
  h * 3600 + m * 60 + s
end.reduce(:+) / arr.size
h = avg / 3600
m = (avg % 3600) / 60
s = avg - h * 3600 - m * 60
puts format('%02d:%02d:%02d', h, m, s)
```